# Setting an MQTT last will and testament in AWS SDK for C++ v2

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I am unable to create a LWT for a topic using AWS IOT SDK for C++ v2. None of the examples demonstrate how to accomplish this and the documentation is not fully clear.

I have tried calling the `SetWill()` function on the connection before calling `Connect()` but this just results in a failed connection.

Our code is based on the AWS simple pub sub code and has been mostly stable (except for experiencing timeouts and reconnects for unknown reasons).

We are targeting an embedded system, our current AWS SDK version is 1.12.8. We may be able to upgrade our SDK version if this is the root cause of this problem (also the disconnect and timeout issues we are observing).

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to setup a rule that properly republishes the message to the shadow/update topic but I do see AWS IOT publish the LWT message if my application exits without performing a graceful disconnect. I'm calling SetWill() prior to Connect with the retain parameter set to "false". If I set retain to "true" then AWS immediately closes the connection after I connect.

This code probably isn't the most efficient way to create the JSON message but it does publish the data in the correct format for a shadow update, if you can get a rule to forward it to the correct shadow topic.

```
    JsonObject jsonLWT;
    JsonObject jsonState;
    JsonObject jsonReported;
    String sLWT;

    jsonReported.WithString("connected", "false");
    jsonState.WithObject("reported", jsonReported);
    jsonLWT.WithObject("state", jsonState);
    sLWT = jsonLWT.View().WriteReadable();

    ByteBuf bbufLWT = ByteBufFromArray((const uint8_t*)sLWT.data(), sLWT.length());


    if ( !connection->SetWill("sdk/test/update", AWS_MQTT_QOS_AT_MOST_ONCE, false, bbufLWT) ) {
        fprintf(stdout, "ERROR: failed to set LWT\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

I'm using the AWS IOT SDK for C++ v2 on a Windows PC. I don't know what version it is but it was built from the latest git source.